modify a file in the repository during a pipeline in Azure Devops
I'm building a pipeline in Azure Devops that basically calls a python file that downloads the iam list from a gcp project.
The problem is that at the end of my pipeline execution, the policy.json file is not actually created in the repository, how can I do this?
def get_policy():

    project_id = "my-project"
    service = discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1')
    
    policy = service.projects().getIamPolicy(
        resource=project_id,
        body={"options": {"requestedPolicyVersion": 3}}
    ).execute()

    return policy


##

policy = get_policy()
request_data["policy"] = policy

    with open("policy.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(policy, file)


When you modify the file during the Pipeline build process, it only changes the file on the Agent machine instead of the files in the repo.
In this case, the policy.json file is not actually created in the repository.
To solve this issue, you can add the git command in the Pipeline to upload the files on the agent machine to the Azure Repo.
Here are the steps:
Step1: You can set the persistCredentials when checkout the repo in YAML Pipeline.
For example:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true

Step2: You need to grant the Contribute permission to the service account: Projectname Build Service(OrganizationName) and Project Collection Build Service(OrganizationName) in Project Settings -> Repositories -> Target Repo -> Permission.

Step3: You can refer to the following git command to upload the policy.json to azure repo.
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'


steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true

- script: python ....

- script: |
    git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
    git config --global user.name "Your Name"

    git add .
    git commit -m "My commit message"
    git push origin HEAD:$(build.sourcebranchname)

For more detailed info, you can refer to my ticket: Set git credentials inside a Azure yaml pipeline
